# Ruby: Best way to parse a conditional array element

Tags: ruby, arrays

I'm doing API calls that will conditionally return a couple different elements. My code is currently:

```
if array['productId']
  value = array['productId'][0]
end
```

I feel like there is a more succinct way of doing this. Some Ruby magic.

Comment: I think this is a hash, not an array. Also, I'm not sure there's anything more succinct than what you have: "If the element exists, than interact with it in a more specific way." You don't get much more succinct than a conditional, unless you're doing this process over and over and would benefit from a loop.

Comment: Basically I'm creating an object and saving it to Active Record. when the model has 10+ fields it feels very unnecessary to have 10 different conditionals to pull the data from. Also see my response to SpyrosP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A better way :

```
value = array['productId'][0] if array['productId']
```

However, array['productId'][0] is not ruby natural. What does your array consist of ?

Comment: Its a JSON response from eBay's API. I read the string and use JSON.parse. I think Matchu might be right that I'm actually dealing with a hash. In that case, am I doing this wrong altogether? Essentially I'm grabbing a couple key data fields from the JSON and saving them into my ActiveRecord database in the form of a Product model. (title, price, gallery_image, etc). I do like the solution presented.... keeps it all on one line, I hate nesting things.

Comment: `value = array['productId'].try(:[], 0)`

Answer (score 2):

Since Ruby 2.3.0, the shortest way is `Array#dig`:

```
array.dig('productId', 0)
```

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0_preview1/Array.html#method-i-dig

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you are using `value` just temporarily or actually using it later, and what you want to do with `value` when the condition is not met. If you want to return `nil` for missing keys, then

```
array['productId'].to_a[0]
```

can work. Otherwise, SpyrosP's answer will be the best.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a bit pedantic, but to make sure it works in all circumstances, you should not check 'not-nil', but rather that it is indexable; something like this:

```
value = array['productId'][0] if array['productId'].is_a? Array
```

Or even better:

```
value = array['productId'][0] if array['productId'].respond_to? '[]'
```

Otherwise your code will fail if `array['productId'] == 2` (which on the other hand seems reasonable, given the key used - I would have gone `product_ids` instead).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a ternary:

```
   value = array['productId'].nil?  ? nil : array['productId'][0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code pattern looks OK; it's possible to be slightly shorter...

```
value = (t = x['productId']) && t[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the *maybe* pattern of [Ick](http://ick.rubyforge.org/), terse and explicit:

```
value = array['productId'].maybe[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

While I think your code is fine (although I'd prefer SpyrosP's one-line version), you have some possibilities:

- Rails has [Object#try](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/try), which would let you do either `array['productId'].try(:[], 0)` or `array['productId'].try(:at, 0)`.
- Some people like the [andand](http://andand.rubyforge.org/) gem, which defines `Object#andand` and is used like `array['productId'].andand[0]`.

Comment: Note: the `try` method is added to Rails via ActiveSupport, and won't work in plain Ruby: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#try

Comment: Hence "Rails has Object#try" ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Ha, I love all the options here. But since I didn't see what I use most, I'll add one more!

`value = array['productId'] && array['productId'].first`

(I prefer `.first` to `[0]` because it reads a little better)

This presumes you'll have an array in `array['productId']`, which is the right way to do it (rather than type-checking).

Otherwise, the biggest diference between this and your original code, is that this results in `value` having `nil` assigned to it if the array doesn't have anything, whereas your original results in `value` not being defined (which may cause errors, depending on how you use it down the road).

Hope that helps!